# Why is the create-new-tags privilege only awarded at 1500 instead of 300?

Tags: discussion, tags, privileges, tag-creation-process

On most Stack Exchange sites except this one, the 'create new tags' privilege is awarded at 300 reputation points, but here on Stack Overflow, it's only awarded at 1500 reputation points. Why is it that here, it's only awarded at 1500 instead of 300?

Comment: The obvious answer is Stack Overflow is 5 times better than all the other sites

Comment: Do you mean five times **better** or five times **bigger**

Comment: Well, you know what they say... bigger is better.

Comment: Even if it's five times bigger (or better), why should you need five times as much reputation?

Comment: Because it is five times easier to reach a certain level of reputation.

Comment: Beacuse even with that crappy new tags need to get cleaned up on a daily basis...

Comment: Most likely this has to do with the size of the user pool and how long it takes to gain rep.  Just looking at the 1 rep users SO is 12 times bigger than the next biggest site.  If you had to wait for 1500 rep on the smaller sites there would be so few people that could add tags.  Again using next biggest site as a comparison they have about 2000-3000 people that could add tags if they used 1500 rep.  On SO using my same guestimation there are 169,000+ people that can add tags.

Comment: @John Stack Overflow already has [1319 pages](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) of tags, and we put some significant efforts into removing the already existing and oftenly misused unuseful tags. So why do you think we need more being created by ragtag and bobtail (sorry).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That should be an answer :-)

Comment: @TylerH Well, it's at least the most upvoted comment. I'll try.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Overflow already has [1319 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) of tags, and we put some significant efforts into removing the already existing and oftenly misused unuseful tags. So why do you think we need more being created by *ragtag and bobtail* (sorry)?

As mentioned in comments we have a [big user pool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321473/why-is-the-create-new-tags-privilege-only-awarded-at-1500-instead-of-300?noredirect=1#comment335504_321473) and want to throttle tag creation for a certain level of trust. Other sites with way smaller audience would suffer from such restriction, and may be unnecessarily prevent the creation of useful tags.

Comment: 1437 pages today, and counting...

Comment: 1453 pages today (did anyone manage to snag a screenshot when it was 1337 pages?)

Comment: 1582 pages today.

Comment: 1889 pages today.

Comment: 1937 pages today.