# Why does [samsung-gear-s2] exist but [samsung-gear-s] is blocked?

Tags: support, tags

The community rejected [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321612/need-samsung-gear-s-tag) for creating a [samsung-gear-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-gear-s) tag - possibly also because it was written like a rant.

It appears to point out a very real problem, though: if we're against creating model-specific tags and want everyone to use [samsung-gear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-gear), why then do we have [samsung-gear-s2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-gear-s2)?

That doesn't seem to make any sense, and it doesn't seem very fair to shut down the discussion with almost zero feedback, and arrogantly close it as a duplicate of the tagging faq, no matter how angry the OP is.

Anybody care to explain their reasoning?

Comment: I like how you got the s and s2 tags mixed up in writing this. It just goes to show how confusing the tagging situation is.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks! (I think I just accidentally flagged your comment....)

Comment: Well, if that upvote was yours, it should have prevented the flag from getting through ;)

Comment: Wild guess: because someone who created [tag:samsung-gear-s2] didn't ask permission on meta, and the requested tag is too similar to the other (system restriction). So.. Burninate Gear S2 tag?

Comment: 4 questions and 1 follower? **Burn it with *fire*!**

Comment: "it was written as a rant" Really? Feel free to re-write. You should have that privilege judging from your score. My qs remains the same - why system serves  the error in this case, why it didn't in the other. Why people can not explain their position when downvoting? They found time to read my rather long post, think about it and come up with a judgement, but didn't have time to explain it? Strange. If they don't explain it to me, I might continue asking question that many will consider as "bad".  Please educate me.

Comment: @Andrew T. If by "too similar" you mean a difference in names, it's not a very good reason. Should I explain why?

Comment: @Paulie_D Right. If we follow that line of thought we should've burnt Linux long time ago and use Windows only.

Comment: @OlegGryb no need, because I *don't* have any problems if you want to create the tag. It's just the restriction is put in place to avoid singular/plural tag. I could create `samsung-gear-d`, but not `samsung-gear-s`. The same as I couldn't create `while-loop-s` ([tag:while-loop] already exists), but I could create `while-loop-d`. Either a bug, or... I don't know.

Comment: @Andrew T. Thanks. It answers my qs. I think, I'm done with this discussion. Thanks to everyone who spent their time to read and answer. A puzzle about downvoters who don't want to explain anything will never be solved. I wouldn't give any credits to them :)

Comment: @AndrewT. not a bug, is intended.

Comment: @fedorqui fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Because [samsung-gear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-gear) exist. There are two checks playing here, one that removes dash from the name, so samsung-gear-s becomes samsunggears and samsunggears triggers the plural check for existingtag[s]?. There are only two way around this, either remove the samsung-gear tag or ask for moderator intervention.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Removing samsung-gear tag looks like the best solution to me. +1

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question asking why the [samsung-gear-s2] tag exists, not why the creation of the [samsung-gear-s] tag is being blocked by the system.

Comment: @RossRidge the sad true is that samsung-gear exist just because. That's why ["we put some significant efforts into removing the already existing and oftenly misused unuseful tags."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321492/792066) People creating tags frivolously is why tagging is hard.

Comment: Regarding dash/depluralizing - how about [samsung-gear-s1] instead ?